# Gradle war manifest version number wrong for release build

Tags: gradle, manifest, release, war

I have a gradle project that builds a war file, and includes a manifest:

```
war {
    archiveName 'archive.war'
    manifest {
        attributes("Implementation-Title": project.name, "Implementation-Version": version, "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date())
    }
}
```

This is fine, but if I run a release build (using the gradle-release plugin https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-release), which updates the project version, then the war file is created with the old version number rather than the new one.

I may be wrong, but I suspect this is happening because the manifest code is running during the Configuration phase rather than the Execution phase. What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: I'd contact the author of the plugin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wrapping the manifest section in "doFirst" fixed it. Using "doLast" resulted in an empty manifest file being created.

Working code:

```
war {
    doFirst {
        manifest {
            attributes("Implementation-Title": project.name, "Implementation-Version": version, "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date())
        }
    }
    archiveName 'infoserverws.war'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I have been stuck on the same problem with the manifest in a jar file.

Comment: @anorakgirl. is your "solution" the same as this answer.. except substitute "jar" for "war" ?