# How to read latest property in property file that is updated earlier in gradle execution

Tags: android, groovy, gradle

For my Android project I have configured the defaultConfig such that it gets the versionName for the AndroidManifest.xml in the generated apk from a version property in ./gradle.properties. This works great. Here is snippet from build.gradle:

```
android {
  ....
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16    //4.1.2 
    targetSdkVersion 19 //4.4 KitKat

    versionName = version  //Read from gradle.properties
    ...
}
```

The problems is that when I use the [townsfolk/gradle-release plugin](https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-release)  that plugin updates the property in ./gradle.properties (bumps it up to the next release name) earlier in the execution.

In this scenario the versionName that is read is from the original ./gradle.properties file before it was modified by gradle-release plugin.

How can I force the reading of the property file just in time to pick up the latest property settings? TIA for your help

Comment: Just found a related post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818755/android-build-with-gradle-release-plugin

Comment: This thread may have a potential solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21272527/gradle-war-manifest-version-number-wrong-for-release-build